# Need to convert value to decimal

Tags: numbers, decimal, converters

I have a value "-3.23108510433268E-15" as string format. I need to convert this to decimal value but I get an error on this

```
Decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal(cotVal);

cotVal= "-3.23108510433268E-15";
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

which language? 
in c# you need to AllowLeadingSign

```
string s = "-3.23108510433268E-15";
        decimal dec = Decimal.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
```